# when i try to move, rotate, scale a vertex-edge-face, scales the whole thing

Tags: transforms, loop

i am a beginner in blender and i cant just scale/move/rotate a vertex. edge or face, it make the movement in the whole thing, ill add a video [video](https://streamable.com/rpldi3)

Comment: The big black circle means proportional editing is on.  Look on top middle of your 3D viewport.  Hotkey to disable proportional editing is 'o' for me.  Proportional editing makes your edit affect more than your selection; in your case, your circle is big enough that it's affecting everything.